# Issues With Database Update

Tags: c#, sql, database

I try to update my database using this code. The message comes up that the database has neen updated but the records do not change in the database. Here are the codes I am using. Please is there any error I am committing?

```
    private void titheEditBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=EPRAISE-PC;Initial Catalog=Cmanager;Integrated Security=True");

        SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("Select Count(MemberID) from Tithe where MemberID = @MemberID", con);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MemberID", titheMemID.Text);

        con.Open();
        int UserExist = (int)sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar();
        if (UserExist > 0)
        {
            SqlCommand sqlcmmd = new SqlCommand("Update Tithe SET Amount = @titheAmount, Date = @titheDate where MemberID = @MemberID AND Date = @titheDate");

            sqlcmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MemberID", titheMemID.Text);
            sqlcmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@titheAmount", titheAmount.Text);
            sqlcmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@titheDate", titheDateTime.Text);
            sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar();
            titheEditMsg.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Such Record Exists");
        }

        con.Close();
        ///titheEditMsg.Visible = false;
    }
```

Comment: What is the error message exactly?

Comment: It gives no error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) *returns* some data which is the first row of the first column. Since your command is `UPDATE`, there is no point to use `ExecuteScalar` in such a case because no data returned on your command.

You need to use [`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your second `sqlcmmd` because your command is `UPDATE` statement and this method just executes your query.

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`.

And don't use `AddWithValue` method. It *may* generate unexpected results. Use [`SqlParameterCollection.Add()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or it's overloads instead.

Read: [Can we stop using `AddWithValue()` already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=EPRAISE-PC;Initial Catalog=Cmanager;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    ....
    ....
    using(SqlCommand sqlcmmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
         sqlcmmd.CommandText = "Update Tithe SET Amount = @titheAmount, Date = @titheDate where MemberID = @MemberID AND Date = @titheDate";
         sqlcmmd.Parameters.Add("@MemberID").Value = titheMemID.Text;
         sqlcmmd.Parameters.Add("@titheAmount").Value = titheAmount.Text;
         sqlcmmd.Parameters.Add("@titheDate").Value = titheDateTime.Text;
         con.Open();
         sqlcmmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That was the issue...besides that i didnt initialize my SqlCommand.

Comment: @EmmanuelGiftEkwemuka You are welcome. You actually initialize your `SqlCommand` with `SqlCommand sqlcmmd = new SqlCommand("Update Tithe SET Amount = @titheAmount, Date = @titheDate where MemberID = @MemberID AND Date = @titheDate");` statement. What do you mean by that?

Comment: @EmmanuelGiftEkwemuka Yeah, that's right. As a better way, use `SqlConnection.CreateCommand()` instead to create a `SqlCommand` associated your `SqlConnection` as I did in my example.

Answer (score 1):

```
   sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar(); //Excute scalar give only Single Cell it Is not meaningful to use to update

 sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();// Use to Inser/Update Statement...
```